# How to add type cheking for commit in vuex with TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuex

I have in my vuex stor an actiontree like this

```
export const actions: SalaryActionTree<SalaryState, RootState> = {
    async setSalaryOperationUnpaidListByUserId(
       {commit}, {user_id, pageNum}) {
        try {
            let res = await SalaryOperationProvider.salaryOperationIndex({
                form: {
                    user_id,
                    payed: '0',
                },
                collectable: {pageNum},
            });
            commit({
                type: 'some-mutatation',
                data: res.data;
            });
        } catch (err) {

        }
    },
}
```

How can I make that a typescript do typechecking for commit parameters?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Vuex by itself doesn't provide any means of typechecking the parameter to commit: [it accepts anything that has a `type` property](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/blob/78ff9833048ee2d599f21c06d881a93aecb1f152/types/index.d.ts#L46).  A [web search](https://www.google.com/search?q=vuex+typescript) found me [this thread](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/issues/564), which offers various options.

Answer (score 0):

It is not an official solution, but you can use [direct-vuex](https://www.npmjs.com/package/direct-vuex).